# How to normalize phone numbers before hashing for facebook custom audience

Tags: facebook, normalization, facebook-marketing-api

Does anyone know how facebook expects the phone numbers to be normalized before hashing and sending it out via Facebook api to be added to custom audience?

Ex: Say I have a number (617) 555-5555

```
A) +1 617 555 5555
B) 6175555555
C) +16175555555
D) Anything else...
```

Comment: Facebook documentation say: "Normalize phone numbers by removing any symbols, letters, and any leading zeroes". https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/users/

Comment: Thank you! I just found that same page and was about to post it :-) thanks for looking it up for me